# Inconsistent string to double conversion on Linux and MacOS

Tags: c++, linux, macos, c++11

I noticed inconsistent behavior when converting a malformed string to a double value. Consider the following code:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>

int main (void)
{
    std::stringstream ss("10.2345asdf");
    double ret;
    ss >> ret;

    // Outputs 10.2345 on Linux, 0 on MacOS
    std::cout << ret << std::endl;  

    return 0;
}
```

On Linux, the program outputs `10.2345`, which is consistent with conversions of malformed strings to `int`, e.g., `10asdf` will be converted to `10`. On MacOS, however, the program outputs `0`, which is inconsistent with Linux and inconsistent with how `int`s are converted using this technique.

It is interesting to see `std::stof` and `std::stod` being integrated into the C++11 standard. Are these new commands related to this issue?

On Linux, I tried both `g++` and `clang++`. On Apple I used `clang` with LLVM version 6.1.0.

Comment: What is the question?